# Measure on a quotient

Tags: measure-theory, lie-groups, hyperbolic-geometry

Can anyone explain me the following :

let $M$ be a hyperbolic manifold and $\Gamma = \Pi_1(M) \subset Iso(\mathbb{H}^n) $. How does the Haar measure on  $Iso(\mathbb{H}^n) $ induces a measure on $Iso(\mathbb{H}^n)/ \Gamma $ ?

This statement can be found in Thurston's notes on $3$-manifolds, in chapter 6, to define Gromov norm

Thank you

Comment: Any measure on $\operatorname{Iso}(\mathbb H^n)$ can be pushed forward to the quotient by the quotient map $\pi:\operatorname{Iso}(\mathbb H^n)\to \operatorname{Iso}(\mathbb H^n)/\Gamma$. Is there any reason why this does not work?

Comment: Such a $\Pi$ is an infinite covering map, this would imply that the measure of the image of any set of positive measure would be infinite, and that is not really good, isn't it ?

Comment: Fair enough. One should restrict to a fundamental domain before pushing forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process by which Haar measure (sometimes) descends to a quotient consists of: (i) restricting the measure to a fundamental domain; (ii) pushing it forward under the quotient map. This requires two ingredients:

1. a fundamental domain of finite measure (which we have here, since the action is cocompact)
2. Haar measure should be both left- and right- invariant (also the case here, and is mentioned by Thurston)

In some situations one gets 2 from 1, as in Proposition 9.20 [in this book](http://books.google.com/books?id=PiDET2fS7H4C).

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the viewpoint of pushing the measure down via a fundamental domain, and the concommitant worry about dependence on that choice, or worry about *finding* a fundamental domain, or worrying about a-priori finite measure... one may also specify a measure on $\Gamma\backslash G$ for unimodular $G$ and unimodular $\Gamma$ (closed subgroup, discrete or not!), by requiring
$$
\int_{\Gamma\backslash G}\Big(\int_\Gamma f(\gamma\cdot \dot{g})\,d\gamma\Big)d\dot{g}
$$
It is not hard to show that the averaging map $f(g)=\int_\Gamma f(\gamma\cdot g)d\gamma$ is a surjection from compactly-supported continuous functions on $G$ to compactly-supported continuous functions on the quotient, so the Riesz-Kakutani-Markov theorem gives a unique measure.

Comment: @5pm ... thx. :)